# Generate a PySpark DataFrame using list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to generate a DataFrame with the following list of column names:

```
cols = [
    'name',
    'age',
    'team',
    'column1',
    'column2',
    'column3',
    'column4',
    'column5',
    'column6',
]

rows = [Row(**{k: '1776-07-04'}) for k in cols]
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows)
```

If I run `df.columns`, the columns from the list above are returned as expected.  But when I run `df.show`, I get the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 9 fields are required while 1 values are provided.`

And so ultimatley I (somewhat) understand why i'm getting this error, but I was under the impression that `1776-07-04` would just be assigned to any/all values.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are creating a Dataframe with 9 Rows but each row has only data for one of the columns.

the right way to create a single row with all 9 columns assigned a value of *'1776-07-04'* is

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(**{k:'1776-07-04' for k in cols})], cols)
>>> df.show()
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|      name|       age|      team|   column1|   column2|   column3|   column4|   column5|   column6|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|1776-07-04|1776-07-04|1776-07-04|1776-07-04|1776-07-04|1776-07-04|1776-07-04|1776-07-04|1776-07-04|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.